# How do I sort my folders in Windows 10 by date modified while keeping my folders on top?

Tags: windows-10

I never had this problem until moving to Windows 10.
I have already looked and saw a mention of if I have it on date modified, then right click again and then hold shift while clicking on name, the folders will be on top but still set to date modified. This is not the case as it's not working for me.
It has the folders on top, but it's not sorted by date at all... unless I'm somehow doing something right.
Is there an exact step by step I need to do?

Comment: Do you mean sorting by a secondary criteria? As in, for folders that have the same modified date, sort by a second criteria? Also, what do you mean by "my folders"?

Comment: I can't help you with this, when I simply sort on date modified, it does so directly keeping folders at the top already, sorted on date modified. Shift clicking name doesn't do anything for me. Are you perhaps using a program that alters explorer? such as classic shell?

Comment: music2myear - No secondary. Simply how folders by default usually always right on top whenever you ever sort by anything. Whether by name or date or size. For some reason folders go anywhere they please when sorting.

LPChip - I'm not using anything that alters explorer.

Comment: How files and folders are sorted has not chnaged in Windows 10.

Comment: Then how do I go about fixing my problem as I only gotten this problem yesterday when I got this new computer with Windows 10 installed.